# Graphical fourier series of a square wave

Tags: fourier-series

This is probably off-topic since it isn't really a question, but I thought that this GIF of the fourier series of a square wave was too cool not to share.

[image]

Comment: I know the guy who makes those. He is Brazilian and makes many of the animations you see on wikipedia.

Comment: There should be some way to edit this DSP visualization into the form of an on-topic question.  Anyone?

Comment: @hotpaw2 Question: Why is this so pretty? :P

Comment: epicycles on epicycles!  @hotpaw2: or just move it to meta.

Comment: Question: why does this work?

Comment: Edit the question and change it to: How do I generate square waves by adding sine waves together? I'd like the answer to that at the moment, what frequency partials go together to make a square wave.

Comment: Like this question:  http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26341/how-do-you-construct-common-waveforms-square-sawtooth-triangle-noise-from-s

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interactive version of the GIF, where you can test how partials add up to shape a certain wave: http://toxicdump.org/stuff/FourierToy.swf